# Access Kubernetes Configmap outside of cluster

Tags: spring, kubernetes

We are experimenting with Kubernetes. Already have developed bunch of Spring boot Microservices which are ready to be integrated with kubernetes.

We would like to keep dev environment (local) simple and not complicate developers with running local kubernetes clusters/ building images etc.

1. Is there any solution to access Kubernetes config-map/secrets outside of its cluster?
2. Is there any way to discover services running in a Kubernetes cluster in a standalone spring boot Microservice app??

Thanks in advance!
A

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes relies on its API servers for all operations. You can use [this API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#-strong-api-overview-strong-) to query/do anything within Kubernetes.

1. Get a configmap with the API: `GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/configmaps/{name}`
2. List all the services: `GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/services/`

How you access the API will depend on your particular setup but you can test it quickly by running `kubectl proxy` and just using `curl` in localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @AV if your question is solved please mark the answer as accepted, if not please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your response! I couldn't access my configmap by its name although i could see it in /api/v1/configmaps                                                                                                                         curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/configmaps/configmap-example
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {},
  "code": 404
}

Comment: @AV if you can get the list, getting a specific one should be easy if you use  the value present in the list at ["metadata"]["selfLink"]. That should be the direct API url for the specific resource.

Comment: Pro tip, if you append `--loglevel=8` to any `kubectl` command you can see the actual API requests being made